# Pandas: Sampling irregular time series when data points available

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

For an irregular time series, `S`, and I would like to take points that are at least `dt` apart, but without changing their timestamps. For example, consider sampling the following series:

```
 time    S
    1    5
    2    1
    9    2
   11   34
   37    1
   41    0
   47    2
```

which resampled with `dt=10` gives

```
 time    S
    1    5
   11   34
   37    1
   47    2
```

Does pandas provide an operation like this?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there is no direct function to do that.

Here an approximative solution :

```
newindex=[0,10,20,30,40]
compatibleindex=S.index.searchsorted(newindex)
S2=S.iloc[compatibleindex]
S3=S2.iloc[abs(S2.index.values-newindex)<10]
print(S2,S3)
```

gives

```
1      5
11    34
37     1
37     1
41     0

1      5
11    34
37     1
41     0
```